# How do you force 'pub get' to get latest from git?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a git dependency in my pubspec.yaml file, how can I force it to be updated when new changes occur in the git repo?

```
flutter pub get / pub get
```

It does not get the latest, as it is in `.pub-cache/git/`

Is there a way to force a specific dependency to update from a git repo referenced in pubspec.yaml?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use

```
flutter packages upgrade
```

to get latest.

```
flutter packages get
```

only gets latests the first time and writes the resolved versions into `pubspec.lock` 
Subsequent `flutter packages get` runs then try to get the versions listed in `pubspec.lock`,
while `flutter packages upgrade` always ignores `pubspec.lock`

Comment: How does this download latest from GIT?

Comment: When the dependency is defined as shown in Xavier's answer, it downloads from Git, otherwise from pub.dev

Answer (score 57):

In your `pubspec.yaml`, you can specify a particular git commit:

```
dependencies:
  http2:
    git:
      url: 'https://github.com/dart-lang/http2.git'
      ref: 'c31df28c3cf076c9aacaed1d77f45b66bb2e01a6'
```

Or if you specify only a branch in "ref":

```
dependencies:
  http2:
    git:
      url: 'https://github.com/dart-lang/http2.git'
      ref: 'master'
```

You need to force the update with `flutter pub upgrade`

Comment: you can also change the branch name (even a non-existing branch name), do a pub get, and then go back to the actual branch. this does get the latest commit.

Comment: When using ref: branch-name how to "tell" pub to get latest commit, without specifying the commit hash explicitly in ref?

Comment: @MatejHlatky you run `flutter pub upgrade`

Answer (score 12):

1. Run `flutter clean` and then `pub get` *(if using flutter then add `flutter` before `pub`)*
2. Ensure to update your package's version number; if the version is the same as the last commit, the package won't get updated.
3. `run pub upgrade`
4. if it still doesn't work you can run `pub cache repair` which reinstalls all your packages

### EDIT

5. ensure dependency is not in dev_dependencies section (yup, that was today!)

Answer (score 1):

`flutter packages upgrade` upgrades all packages' sub-version which might not be the thing you are looking for (using some specific package version for some reason etc.). `pub cache repair` gets the job done by reinstalling all the packages but it also takes time. **Working with refs has disadvantages** like missing the most current updates on a branch.

There are 2 other options/hacks to avoid all this:

1. delete package info from `pubspec.lock` and run `flutter pub get`
2. update `ref` value to most current commit's hash value. run `flutter pub get` then **rewrite your branch name** again to your ref value.